# WSO2 API Manager : "Uncaught TypeError" on importing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I try to import this valid Swagger.json file (working with latest Swagger UI), I get this error in javascript Console (nothing on screen) :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5q5SPyg8HONYWlEYXdZRkd2aWs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at APIDesigner.has_resources (api-design.js:301)
```

This is related to this code :

```
APIDesigner.prototype.has_resources = function(){
    if(Object.keys(this.api_doc.paths).length == 0) 
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

It's like if "this.api_doc.paths" was undefined, but well, there are "paths" in my file.

My other swagger.json files for other APIs generated with the same Swagger 1.5.10 framework are all importables.

Comment: I tried this in APIM 2.0.0 and it worked without any issue (tested in Chrome and Firefox). Can you try in a different browser?

Comment: I had tried on Chrome and Firefox, I highly doubt the browser version would be involved in this, more the version of the swagger-ui you package and modify. After all this time, you guess we've given up about WSO2 for more reliable tools.